# How to know the file type of the file which you are forcing the user to download?

Tags: php, file-handling

I am trying to force the user to download a file. For that my script is:

```
$file = "file\this.zip";        
header("Cache-Control: public");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file");
header("Content-Type: application/zip"); //This is what I need
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
readfile($file);
```

The files I  am going to upload my not be .zip all the time so I want to know the content type of the image I am going to receive in $file.
How to accomplish this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I always put `application/octet-stream` (or somwething like that) as the browser can't then try and display it in any way, it will always force the user to Save / Run, then the file type is often inferred by the extension.

Answer (score 2):

For images, the most reliable is [getimagesize()](http://www.php.net/getimagesize). For any other type, the [Fileinfo](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-open.php) functions are the right thing.

I second what ck says, though: When forcing a download, `octet-stream` is the best choice to prevent things from opening in the browser or the respective client application.

Answer (score 0):

Hey, on the link below you can see the values of the Content-Type that you need:

[Internet Media Type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type)

There are just too many to list here
Ladislav

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I did it myself.

I used

```
$type = filetype($file); //to know the type
```

Comment: That'll just return 'file' for all of your files. Not what you want.

Comment: Yeah, I just noticed. I have used application/octet-stream as suggested

Answer (score 0):

You need to send the *mime-type* there. You can get this in PHP by using the [`mime_content_type`](http://www.php.net/mime_content_type) function. There's also the [Fileinfo](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.fileinfo.php) extension which provides a way of getting lots of file information, including the mime type.